# recovery postgreSQL database from pg files

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.2, database-backups, data-recovery

i have postgresql 9.2 that service not run

i just have data file from database(postgreSQL/9.2 installation directory )

i copy data folder to postgres in other system(the same version) and service not run

how to recovery my data?(how to recovery from pg_data file)

please help me

thanks

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-file.html  . You must copy the WHOLE data directory, not just parts of it, including `pg_clog`, `pg_xlog` etc. Otherwise it *will not work*. As for why it won't start, check the log files!

Comment: thanks.
where replace data folder, don't run service of postgres.the error:
 service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs

Comment: Check the *PostgresSQL* log files, from the `pg_log` directory.